# How to create a shared project in Gradle without a jar dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have 4 projects under my root project: shared, proj1, proj2 and proj3.

Proj1, proj2 and proj3 are all use the 'shared' project code. I'm trying to understand how to include the sources from the shared project inside each of the 3 other projects in such a way that when I'll create the projects' archives and javadoc and sources jars they will also contain the shared project content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: in each of the 3 dependent projects (proj1, proj2 and proj3) the source sets should have been expanded in the following way:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs(project(':shared').sourceSets.main.java)
        }
    }
}
```

That way, when using Gradle's built-in 'javadoc' and sources tasks for each of the projects, the output jars will include the 'shared' project content as well (i.e. .class files, documentation and .java files).

Comment: This is _almost_ the perfect answer for me. The part I'm missing is that `:shared` has its own dependencies and I can't seem to import those without making `:shared` a dependency too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each module (~project) has its own build.gradle. Inside one of the project's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project('shared')
    // If you have a dependency tree between projects
    compile project('project2')
    ...
}
```

In your settings.gradle, which is global

```
include 'project1', 'project2', 'project3', 'shared'
// Only if your project is not on on the same path
project(':project2').projectDir = new File('../stuff/project2')
```

Comment: Thank you, but in that case when compiling the projects, 'project2' jar will contain only its .class files, and therefore will required the 'shared' jar as dependency. I'm looking for a solution that project2 jar will contain the .class files of the 'shared' project as well.
Maybe it wasn't clear enough in my question

Comment: Add 'shared' as a dependency in the project2 project too. You can add it as provided instead of compiled to prevent having it twice.